# canon 60d ten second timer remote

Tags: canon, remote

I bought a cheap infrared remote and its range is very limited. Also I could only find as another option a two second timer. Most cheaper digital cameras have 10 second timer. How do I get this for my 60d?

Comment: The assumption seems to be that you can use the 10 second timer option that is built in to the 60D and have plenty of time to move to the position you want to be in after pressing the shutter button on the camera. Distances that would take more than 10 seconds for most users to cover are also beyond the range of an infrared remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press the "Drive" button next to your camera's top display (between the AF and ISO buttons), and scroll through until you get the same icon as the 2 second timer but without the number 2 next to it. That's the 10 second timer.

Here's the icon from the 60D user manual:

[image]